# discarding Kodak Carousel trays

Tags: used-equipment, kodak

I am going through MANY old family slides, editing with extreme prejudice, and scanning.   I'm going to have nearly 100 empty Kodak Carousel trays (both 80-slide and 140-slide varieties), and I'm not sure what to do with them.

Have offered them on eBay for just the cost of shipping; neighborhood forsale lists; called local camera shops.  I am at wit's end. I've heard that even recycling isn't so great, because of the metal parts and because that very hard plastic doesn't recycle well.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You'd think this question had been asked many many times, but I searched ...

Comment: This isn't _really_ a photographic problem. You have some waste to get rid of. I would suggest asking your local municipal waste authority how to discard of them. Unless a charity/thrift shop will take them? Reuse and recycling are good...but sometimes we're left with no alternatives.

Comment: I'd guess that a lot of the times this got asked predates [SO] and company.

Comment: @RustyShackleford Maybe they can be disposed of as electronic waste?  I hope you're not discarding the slides after scanning.

Comment: Oh that's a good idea - similar type plastics I imagine.

Comment: Yeah, I am discarding most of them.   There are 5-10,000 of them.  I'm doing pretty decent scans, 4000dpi/48bits on a Nikon film scanner; reduce to 8bits/channel after fixing levels and some light USM'ing.  Understand that most of these are "snapshot" quality - not very sharp, sometimes blurred, and fairly uninteresting - probably of virtually no interest to anyone except me and my only surviving sibling.   I AM saving the ones that seem particularly special.

Comment: This question is about waste management, not photography per se.

Comment: @xiota Whatever.  I imagined this was a question that photographers might have some insight on.   Thanks to others for the helpful answers.

Comment: While it is something some photographers might have insight on dealing with, it's not something photographers would be expected to have expertise in.  Another option is to put up a "for free" listing on craigslist or equivalent.  Maybe someone could use them in a [DIY project](https://www.google.com/search?q=diy+slide+carousel+project+craft&tbm=isch) or something.

Comment: Save them to sell on eBay. Someone will NEED them at some point, and you’ll be one of the few suppliers/upcyclers around. Sharing old technology is pretty important.

Comment: I listed 'em on eBay awhile and no luck.   They take up a fair amount of space; but I guess that's what attics are for.

Comment: Related question: [I want to donate Kodak 35mm equipment to a non profit](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/96182)

Comment: Contact Film Photography Project and ask if they have any use for them.

Comment: No response yet.   There's a local place that takes junk that artists might could use, and I think they'll take 'em.   I'm going to save 10 each of the 80-slide and 140-slide sizes (in the conveniently sized boxes that we shipped 'em in).

Comment: Recycle them if you can't sell or give them away. This isn't a photography question. It's common sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you've exhausted the possibilities of getting them re-used for their original purpose.

So it's a simple rubbish-disposal problem.   Talk to your refuse collector.   Yes, it would be nice if everything could be re-cycled.  Maybe one day!   You've done what you can, no need to beat yourself up over it.

Answer (score 1):

Goodwill does take the empty slide carousels